# Why i dont see in the Form the variable newGPUTextLabel when running the application?

Tags: c#

```
private void GPULabels()
        {



                newGPUTextLabel.Location = new Point(340, 100);
                newGPUTextLabel.Height = 250;
                newGPUTextLabel.Width = 500;
                newGPUTextLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                newGPUTextLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
                newGPUTextLabel.Text = " - הטמפרטורה כעת";
                button3.Enabled = false;

                newGPULabel.Location = new Point(250, 100);
                newGPULabel.Height = 250;
                newGPULabel.Width = 500;
                newGPULabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                newGPULabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
                button3.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void CPULabels()
        {
            temperature_label.Location = new Point(250, 200);
            temperature_label.Height = 250;
            temperature_label.Width = 500;
            temperature_label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            temperature_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);

            textMode_label.Location = new Point(340, 200);
            textMode_label.Height = 250;
            textMode_label.Width = 500;
            textMode_label.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            textMode_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 35, FontStyle.Bold);
            textMode_label.Text = " - הטמפרטורה כעת";
            button3.Enabled = false;
        }
```

I added the labels to the controls and did instance fo each one.
I also call the two functions in the constructor.

I see on the Form all the labels  except: newGPUTextLabel

The Form1 size is: 800x600

If i change the line:

```
newGPUTextLabel.Location = new Point(340, 100);
```

to

```
newGPUTextLabel.Location = new Point(340, 10);
```

So i see the newGPUTextLabel but its on the top of the Form and i want it to be close to the textMode_label.

Comment: is there a Visible Property that you need to set..?

Comment: Did you remember to do "this.Controls.Add(newGPUTextLabel); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds as though the newGPUTextLabel is not in the same container as the other controls.

I would look in the designer to see where it is added (one of the controls may be in a panel or group box and the other may not be, for example).